# Is there way to work with separated Play! 2 libraries in another scala project?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, playframework-2.1

I want to use some of the Play2 libraries (for example, Json API and WS API) in separate scala project. Is there any way to add libs to a `libraryDependency` list at `built.scala`. Or may be I need to do something else.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To depend on play-core we need to add in `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion :="2.10.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("play" % "play_2.10" % "2.1.0")

resolvers ++= Seq("Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/")
```

this for scala and play version 2.1.
Additional links [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/SBTDependencies) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/dlWxRvnOVcY).